# Get other part of array when match found

Tags: php, arrays, regex, title

Here's the regex I'm working with. It works fine, but now I'm trying to get the results.

Basically, if the name/property/etc contains "title" I want it to echo the contents of the title meta tag.

In other words, I want the corresponding out[2], not out[1], when out[1] contains "title" (case insensitive).

```
  $pattern = '
  ~<\s*meta\s

  # using lookahead to capture type to $1
    (?=[^>]*?
    \b(?:name|property|http-equiv)\s*=\s*
    (?|"\s*([^"]*?)\s*"|\'\s*([^\']*?)\s*\'|
    ([^"\'>]*?)(?=\s*/?\s*>|\s\w+\s*=))
  )

  # capture content to $2
  [^>]*?\bcontent\s*=\s*
    (?|"\s*([^"]*?)\s*"|\'\s*([^\']*?)\s*\'|
    ([^"\'>]*?)(?=\s*/?\s*>|\s\w+\s*=))
  [^>]*>

  ~ix';

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $link_html, $out))
{
    foreach ($out[1] as $out)
    {
        echo $out.'<br>';
    }   
}
```

Comment: why don't you use an html parser instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for a Regex but using an HTML Parser and XPath would be so much easier and more readable:

```
<?php

$html = <<< HTML
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="author" lang="en" content="Gordon" />
        <meta name="title" lang="en" content="match this" />
        <meta property="title" lang="en" content="and this" />
        <meta http-equiv="title" lang="en" content="and also this" />
        <meta foo="title" content="but not this" />
    </head>
    <body>Use DOMDocument for HTML parsing instead</body>
</html>
HTML;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate(
    '//meta[
       @*[
         contains("name|property|http-equiv", name())
         and contains(., "title")
         ]
       ]/@content'
);

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
match this
and this
and also this
```

The XPath means *find all content attributes of any meta tags where any of the attribute names is part of the string "name|property|http-equiv" and which contains the value "title"* in that attribute.

As you can hopefully see, the XPath itself almost reads as if it was natural language (as opposed to the regex you used).

Comment: Oh wow, I'd used XPath a long time ago and then forgotten about it......you're absolutely right.....I'll accept when it allows me.... thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

That should be possible by capturing the array index in the `foreach` loop, like this:

```
foreach ($out[1] as $index => $out) {
    if(stristr($out, 'title')) echo $out[2][$index].'<br>';
}
```